# Bootstrap 4 navbar multiple elements position issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to position three different elements in Bootstrap 4 mobile screens and desktop screen. I need position in mobile as following way:

Left side image, center logo image and right side toggle navigation bar button.

I have tried but I can just position the right toggle button and center logo image. If I try to put left image it messes up the whole navbar. Please see the code below.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse" id="mainNav">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarExample" aria-controls="navbarExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="container nav_div">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-logo mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarExample">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                  <?php
                  foreach ($this->session->userdata('menu') as $key => $value) {
                    if($value->label == 'Home'){
                      $function_nm = 'index';
                    }elseif ($value->label == 'My info') {
                      $function_nm = 'myInfo';
                    }elseif ($value->label == 'Inbox') {
                      $function_nm = 'inbox';
                    }elseif ($value->label == 'Settings') {
                      $function_nm = 'setting';
                    }
                    ?>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>customerController/<?php echo $function_nm ?>"><?php echo $value->label ?></a></li>
                    <?php
                  }
                  ?>

                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>customerController/logout">Logout</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
<!--       <div style="text-align: center;">test</div>-->
    </nav>
```

----------css--------------

```
#mainNav
{
    background: #00a3d6;
}
.navbar-toggler
{
    font-size: 1.85rem;
}
.navbar-logo
{
    font-size: 16px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

When this menu opens in desktop view, the left image should be positioned to the right side. The logo image left with the navigation menu next to it. Currently, the logo and navigation menu are in perfect position. I just need to position that extra image on mobile and desktop as described.

[image]

For reference, I uploaded one sample image for mobile screens and desktop screens that I want.[image]

Comment: You could use flex, make three divs(left image, center logo and navbar toggle) and set to each of them to `flex: 1`. Each div will take the same width, then if you can use padding to make it more right or left..

Comment: Don't post PHP code, post your *output* HTML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to achieve that goal is to position that "other image" as the **first** item in the HTML (within the navbar) and then give it the class 
 `order-md-last`. That will re-order the image as the *last* item on screens that are medium (`md`) or larger (and revert to default on smaller screens).

Also, make sure you are using actual Bootstrap 4 classes and navbar components. You aren't currently doing that judging by your code.

Here's a working code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page for testing):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="navbar-brand order-md-last">
   <!-- the 'other image' comes here -->
   <img class="" src="https://placehold.it/130x30" alt="other image">
</div>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <!-- the 'logo image' comes here -->
    <img src="https://placehold.it/60x30" alt="logo image">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

You'll also notice that I wrapped that "other image" in a div with the class `navbar-brand`. That's to make it vertically align the same way as the logo image.